# Apply transforms on a group to each element after ungrouping

Tags: svg

We're working on a project to create an SVG editor from scratch (we can't use any external libraries) - and we've hit a snag.

We need to create a tool to group shapes, which we've managed to do, and we can also use all of our tools (scale/translate/rotate) on the group. However, we're stuck at the point of trying to ungroup. I think the two options are either take the transforms from the group element and then somehow apply them to each element, or ignore transforming the group and just apply the transforms to each element from the beginning.

Has anyone worked with this or have any starting ideas that might help? Because transforms aren't commutative, and for example, rotation is around a different relative point for each shape, we're pretty stuck.

Comment: you could look at what svg-edit does.

Comment: "rotation is around a different relative point for each shape"...

 what do you mean by this? there are no relative points in svg transfroms...

Answer (score 0):

Transforms work in a nested fashion.  So to ungroup and apply the groups transform to the children, all you need to do is prepend the parent groups' transform(s) to the children's transforms.

So the following two SVGs are equivalent:

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100,30)">
    <rect width="100" height="80" transform="rotate(30, 50,40)"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<br/>

<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="80" transform="translate(100,30) rotate(30, 50,40)"/>
</svg>
```